# MySQL Tablespace and Data File on External Disk

Tags: mysql

Sure we are all good. I was trying to create a MySQL Tablespace on a disk where the MySQL database is not installed so that I can explicitly specify that tables should be created on that Tablespace rather than using the database default Tablespace. I use the followng query to do the creation of the Tablespace but I kept getting error :

```
CREATE TABLESPACE sampleTableSpace ADD DATAFILE 'D:/SampleTableSpace/sampleTableSpace.ibd' engine = innodb;
```

I got the following error using the above query to create the Tablespace :

```
ERROR 3121 (HY000): The DATAFILE location must be in a known directory.
```

I do not know how to fix this but I was thinking probably because the MySQL is installed on C drive and i was trying to create the Tablespace and Data File on D drive.

Please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0.21 and later, you must teach InnoDB which locations are allowed for tablespace files.

See https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-consistency-for-datafile-locations-in-mysql-8-0-21/ for the announcement and full explanation of this feature.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_directories for documentation of the `innodb_directories` option used to specify the list of locations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference guide, i appreciate you and God bless you. I followed the reference guide and understood the update in MySQL 8. Kudos to you.